# Evaluating strings to Classes at runtime

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, autoload

Hello guys i have a static function that is common to several models in my laravel 5 application, and i want to use one route to call the function in the particular model. this is my approach...

```
Route::get('/obj/{model}/call', function($model){
   $model = ucfirst($model);  //make the first letter uppercase
   $model::callObjParam();    //evaluate string to model
});
```

so the string resolves to this ::

```
'asset' -  'obj/asset/call' using the 'Asset' model, 
'user' - 'obj/user/call' using the 'User' model,
'Role' - 'obj/role/call' using the 'Role' model
```

But i keep getting an error:

> FatalThrowableError in routes.php line 122
>   Class 'Asset' not found

Is there a way to evaluate strings to classes?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I guess your models resides under `App` namespace, so you have to provide the fully qualified name of the model: `"\\App\\$model"`.

Comment: Why the hell do you need to wrap a global function in a class?

Comment: @tereško different approaches to different problems, and this seems to be the best approach for what i'm trying to do.

Comment: @Andaeiii sine PHP 5.3 we have **namespaces** for that. If you want to group a global function, you should be using a namspace and not a "static class" hack.

Comment: @tereško so in your opinion what would be your best approach to my problem.

Comment: use `new` or DI container, or, if it really is a simple function, then write it as a simple function

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad idea to do that but if you really want to do this, use full namespace of a class:

```
$model = 'App\\' . studly_case($model);
$model::method();
```

Also, you should validate input model name and use [`studly_case()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-studly-case) helper to transform the string to a proper class name.

Comment: wow, trying it right away, i hope it works, i'd get back to you. thanks

Comment: thanks this works... but i was having an issue at '\App\' and then i realized i needed double slashes... that is. '\App\\' and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

also you can do this if you have just 3 case :

```
switch($model){
    case 'asset' :
        Asset::callObj();
        break;
    case 'user' :
        User::calObj() ;
        break;
    case 'role' : 
        Role::calObj() ;
        break;
    case default : 
        default::callObj()
        break;
}
```

Comment: yea.. i was trying to avoid this, my guess was that there are better ways of doing it, this works though, but in certain scenarios the former is usually needed... imagine having over 100 models. and each model implementing its own function in a different way. you cant use this.